# SQL Server Loop to Simulate Order Capacity (infinite loop problem)

Tags: sql, loops, while-loop

I've been working on this one for a while. I can't get the statement to generate the next 'fresh order' from the list, it just loops the first one. I'm not great with the language, and this is my best effort at making this work...

setting up tables to test:

```
if exists(select [name] from tempdb.sys.tables where [name] like '#itemwc%')
  begin
    drop table #itemwc;
  end;

if exists(select [name] from tempdb.sys.tables where [name] like '#workcell%')
  begin
    drop table #workcell;
  end;

if exists(select [name] from tempdb.sys.tables where [name] like '#itemcap%')
  begin
    drop table #itemcap;
  end;

if exists(select [name] from tempdb.sys.tables where [name] like '#o%')
  begin
    drop table #o;
  end;

if exists(select [name] from tempdb.sys.tables where [name] like '#w%')
  begin
    drop table #w;
  end;

if exists(select [name] from tempdb.sys.tables where [name] like '#orders%')
  begin
    drop table #orders;
  end;


begin /* table population */

create table #itemwc

(
  item varchar(259), 
  workcell varchar(259), 
  cellcap float
)

insert into #itemwc
(item, workcell, cellcap)
values
('Contactor Size 0', 'A', 30),
('Contactor Size 1', 'A', 16),
('Contactor Size 1', 'B', 35),
('Contactor Size 1', 'C', 16),
('Contactor Size 2', 'C', 8)


create table #workcell
(
  workcell varchar(259),
  fwdratio float,
  bckratio varchar(259),
  item1 varchar(259),
  item2 varchar(259)
)

insert into #workcell
(workcell, fwdratio, bckratio, item1, item2)
values
('A', 1.875, 0.533333333333333, 'Contactor Size 0', 'Contactor Size 1'),
('B', 1, 1, 'Contactor Size 1', null),
('C', 2, 0.5, 'Contactor Size 1', 'Contactor Size 2')


create table #itemcap
(
  item varchar(259),
  dailycap float
)

insert into #itemcap
(item, dailycap)
values
('Contactor Size 0', 30),
('Contactor Size 1', 67),
('Contactor Size 2', 8)


create table #o
(
  orderno float,
  item varchar(259),
  qty float,
  needdate date
)

insert into #o
(orderno, item, qty, needdate)
values
(1, 'Contactor Size 1', 2, '2019-12-19'),
(2, 'Contactor Size 2', 12, '2020-02-03'),
(3, 'Contactor Size 0', 14, '2020-01-28'),
(4, 'Contactor Size 2', 30, '2019-12-11'),
(5, 'Contactor Size 1', 18, '2019-12-04'),
(6, 'Contactor Size 0', 7, '2020-01-08'),
(7, 'Contactor Size 0', 1, '2020-01-04'),
(8, 'Contactor Size 1', 39, '2020-01-15'),
(9, 'Contactor Size 0', 15, '2019-12-21'),
(10, 'Contactor Size 2', 9, '2020-01-26'),
(11, 'Contactor Size 2', 21, '2019-12-11'),
(12, 'Contactor Size 0', 14, '2020-01-04'),
(13, 'Contactor Size 1', 8, '2020-01-26'),
(14, 'Contactor Size 0', 3, '2019-12-31'),
(15, 'Contactor Size 1', 13, '2019-12-09'),
(16, 'Contactor Size 1', 28, '2020-01-26'),
(17, 'Contactor Size 2', 15, '2019-11-25'),
(18, 'Contactor Size 0', 19, '2020-01-25'),
(19, 'Contactor Size 0', 20, '2019-12-03'),
(20, 'Contactor Size 1', 17, '2020-01-15'),
(21, 'Contactor Size 0', 37, '2020-01-22'),
(22, 'Contactor Size 1', 20, '2020-02-06'),
(23, 'Contactor Size 1', 24, '2020-01-27'),
(24, 'Contactor Size 1', 28, '2020-01-09'),
(25, 'Contactor Size 0', 1, '2020-02-07'),
(26, 'Contactor Size 1', 27, '2020-01-21'),
(27, 'Contactor Size 2', 15, '2019-12-12'),
(28, 'Contactor Size 0', 20, '2019-12-31'),
(29, 'Contactor Size 2', 39, '2020-01-15'),
(30, 'Contactor Size 0', 26, '2020-01-08'),
(31, 'Contactor Size 1', 1, '2019-12-12'),
(32, 'Contactor Size 2', 5, '2019-11-30'),
(33, 'Contactor Size 2', 33, '2019-12-24'),
(34, 'Contactor Size 1', 23, '2020-01-25'),
(35, 'Contactor Size 2', 35, '2019-12-28'),
(36, 'Contactor Size 2', 5, '2020-01-24'),
(37, 'Contactor Size 0', 33, '2020-01-01'),
(38, 'Contactor Size 2', 11, '2020-01-07'),
(39, 'Contactor Size 0', 9, '2019-12-24'),
(40, 'Contactor Size 2', 13, '2020-01-17'),
(41, 'Contactor Size 1', 33, '2019-11-25'),
(42, 'Contactor Size 0', 17, '2020-02-04'),
(43, 'Contactor Size 1', 15, '2020-01-25'),
(44, 'Contactor Size 1', 13, '2019-12-18'),
(45, 'Contactor Size 1', 10, '2019-12-26'),
(46, 'Contactor Size 1', 6, '2020-02-10'),
(47, 'Contactor Size 1', 39, '2019-12-30'),
(48, 'Contactor Size 1', 13, '2020-01-28'),
(49, 'Contactor Size 2', 10, '2020-01-28'),
(50, 'Contactor Size 0', 27, '2019-12-12'),
(51, 'Contactor Size 1', 35, '2020-01-13'),
(52, 'Contactor Size 1', 27, '2019-12-27'),
(53, 'Contactor Size 2', 2, '2019-12-28'),
(54, 'Contactor Size 1', 38, '2020-01-30'),
(55, 'Contactor Size 1', 33, '2020-01-03'),
(56, 'Contactor Size 2', 21, '2020-02-05'),
(57, 'Contactor Size 2', 11, '2019-12-17'),
(58, 'Contactor Size 1', 10, '2019-12-31'),
(59, 'Contactor Size 0', 26, '2020-01-03'),
(60, 'Contactor Size 2', 4, '2020-01-20'),
(61, 'Contactor Size 0', 15, '2019-12-02'),
(62, 'Contactor Size 1', 17, '2020-01-18'),
(63, 'Contactor Size 1', 1, '2020-01-26'),
(64, 'Contactor Size 0', 15, '2019-12-27'),
(65, 'Contactor Size 1', 3, '2019-12-22'),
(66, 'Contactor Size 2', 34, '2019-12-25'),
(67, 'Contactor Size 2', 38, '2020-01-22'),
(68, 'Contactor Size 1', 12, '2019-12-25'),
(69, 'Contactor Size 2', 36, '2020-01-03'),
(70, 'Contactor Size 1', 28, '2020-01-06'),
(71, 'Contactor Size 2', 10, '2020-01-13'),
(72, 'Contactor Size 0', 28, '2019-11-30'),
(73, 'Contactor Size 1', 25, '2019-12-08'),
(74, 'Contactor Size 0', 24, '2020-01-04'),
(75, 'Contactor Size 2', 18, '2020-02-10'),
(76, 'Contactor Size 2', 25, '2019-11-28'),
(77, 'Contactor Size 1', 39, '2020-01-22'),
(78, 'Contactor Size 0', 31, '2019-12-01'),
(79, 'Contactor Size 1', 18, '2019-12-06'),
(80, 'Contactor Size 0', 12, '2019-12-02'),
(81, 'Contactor Size 0', 4, '2020-02-03'),
(82, 'Contactor Size 0', 27, '2020-01-05'),
(83, 'Contactor Size 0', 19, '2020-02-05'),
(84, 'Contactor Size 0', 15, '2020-01-09'),
(85, 'Contactor Size 1', 21, '2020-01-16'),
(86, 'Contactor Size 1', 16, '2020-01-21'),
(87, 'Contactor Size 2', 26, '2020-01-09'),
(88, 'Contactor Size 0', 1, '2019-11-25'),
(89, 'Contactor Size 0', 5, '2020-02-09'),
(90, 'Contactor Size 2', 34, '2020-01-24'),
(91, 'Contactor Size 0', 21, '2019-12-13'),
(92, 'Contactor Size 2', 22, '2019-11-30'),
(93, 'Contactor Size 0', 31, '2020-02-11'),
(94, 'Contactor Size 2', 28, '2019-11-24'),
(95, 'Contactor Size 1', 20, '2020-02-06'),
(96, 'Contactor Size 0', 18, '2020-01-20'),
(97, 'Contactor Size 1', 3, '2019-12-19'),
(98, 'Contactor Size 1', 20, '2020-01-29'),
(99, 'Contactor Size 2', 37, '2020-01-12'),
(100, 'Contactor Size 1', 18, '2020-01-16'),
(101, 'Contactor Size 2', 16, '2020-01-22'),
(102, 'Contactor Size 1', 25, '2020-01-21'),
(103, 'Contactor Size 2', 1, '2020-01-24'),
(104, 'Contactor Size 1', 11, '2020-01-28'),
(105, 'Contactor Size 0', 12, '2020-01-06'),
(106, 'Contactor Size 2', 31, '2019-12-29'),
(107, 'Contactor Size 1', 38, '2019-12-09'),
(108, 'Contactor Size 2', 27, '2020-02-11'),
(109, 'Contactor Size 1', 12, '2020-01-17'),
(110, 'Contactor Size 2', 21, '2019-12-15'),
(111, 'Contactor Size 1', 17, '2020-02-07'),
(112, 'Contactor Size 2', 38, '2019-12-23'),
(113, 'Contactor Size 1', 34, '2020-01-27'),
(114, 'Contactor Size 1', 27, '2020-02-07'),
(115, 'Contactor Size 0', 30, '2019-11-28'),
(116, 'Contactor Size 2', 12, '2020-01-26'),
(117, 'Contactor Size 2', 10, '2019-12-29'),
(118, 'Contactor Size 2', 31, '2020-01-18'),
(119, 'Contactor Size 1', 4, '2020-01-25'),
(120, 'Contactor Size 2', 12, '2020-01-02'),
(121, 'Contactor Size 2', 17, '2020-02-11'),
(122, 'Contactor Size 2', 39, '2020-02-04'),
(123, 'Contactor Size 1', 1, '2019-12-08'),
(124, 'Contactor Size 0', 37, '2019-12-07'),
(125, 'Contactor Size 1', 31, '2020-01-11'),
(126, 'Contactor Size 1', 12, '2020-01-02'),
(127, 'Contactor Size 1', 19, '2019-11-26'),
(128, 'Contactor Size 1', 22, '2019-11-29'),
(129, 'Contactor Size 1', 39, '2020-01-02'),
(130, 'Contactor Size 0', 14, '2019-12-26'),
(131, 'Contactor Size 2', 18, '2019-12-17'),
(132, 'Contactor Size 2', 28, '2020-01-28'),
(133, 'Contactor Size 1', 40, '2019-12-20'),
(134, 'Contactor Size 0', 5, '2020-01-29'),
(135, 'Contactor Size 0', 8, '2020-01-23'),
(136, 'Contactor Size 2', 29, '2020-02-05'),
(137, 'Contactor Size 1', 8, '2019-12-19'),
(138, 'Contactor Size 1', 18, '2020-01-15'),
(139, 'Contactor Size 2', 29, '2019-12-21'),
(140, 'Contactor Size 1', 13, '2020-01-10'),
(141, 'Contactor Size 1', 22, '2019-11-25'),
(142, 'Contactor Size 1', 37, '2019-12-08'),
(143, 'Contactor Size 0', 1, '2020-01-06'),
(144, 'Contactor Size 0', 23, '2020-01-07'),
(145, 'Contactor Size 1', 9, '2019-12-28'),
(146, 'Contactor Size 1', 8, '2019-11-25'),
(147, 'Contactor Size 0', 2, '2020-01-05'),
(148, 'Contactor Size 0', 39, '2020-01-01'),
(149, 'Contactor Size 1', 34, '2020-02-10'),
(150, 'Contactor Size 0', 33, '2019-12-17'),
(151, 'Contactor Size 2', 10, '2019-12-02'),
(152, 'Contactor Size 1', 9, '2020-02-08'),
(153, 'Contactor Size 1', 21, '2019-12-18'),
(154, 'Contactor Size 1', 29, '2020-01-27'),
(155, 'Contactor Size 1', 31, '2020-01-21'),
(156, 'Contactor Size 0', 29, '2019-12-14'),
(157, 'Contactor Size 2', 40, '2019-12-22'),
(158, 'Contactor Size 1', 25, '2019-12-20'),
(159, 'Contactor Size 2', 31, '2020-02-10'),
(160, 'Contactor Size 0', 32, '2020-02-07'),
(161, 'Contactor Size 0', 18, '2020-02-11'),
(162, 'Contactor Size 2', 2, '2019-12-15'),
(163, 'Contactor Size 2', 19, '2020-01-20'),
(164, 'Contactor Size 1', 1, '2020-02-02'),
(165, 'Contactor Size 1', 31, '2019-12-27'),
(166, 'Contactor Size 2', 36, '2020-01-12'),
(167, 'Contactor Size 2', 31, '2019-12-04'),
(168, 'Contactor Size 2', 3, '2019-12-03'),
(169, 'Contactor Size 1', 10, '2019-12-24'),
(170, 'Contactor Size 2', 3, '2020-01-21'),
(171, 'Contactor Size 2', 14, '2020-02-06'),
(172, 'Contactor Size 2', 17, '2020-01-11'),
(173, 'Contactor Size 2', 22, '2020-01-15'),
(174, 'Contactor Size 1', 35, '2020-01-07'),
(175, 'Contactor Size 2', 17, '2020-02-07'),
(176, 'Contactor Size 1', 7, '2019-12-01'),
(177, 'Contactor Size 1', 14, '2019-12-07'),
(178, 'Contactor Size 0', 19, '2019-12-18'),
(179, 'Contactor Size 1', 11, '2020-01-10'),
(180, 'Contactor Size 1', 25, '2020-02-12'),
(181, 'Contactor Size 1', 24, '2019-12-04'),
(182, 'Contactor Size 2', 1, '2020-02-12'),
(183, 'Contactor Size 0', 2, '2020-01-14'),
(184, 'Contactor Size 0', 14, '2019-12-20'),
(185, 'Contactor Size 0', 22, '2019-12-09'),
(186, 'Contactor Size 0', 28, '2019-12-29'),
(187, 'Contactor Size 0', 23, '2019-12-05'),
(188, 'Contactor Size 0', 25, '2020-01-03'),
(189, 'Contactor Size 1', 27, '2020-02-05'),
(190, 'Contactor Size 2', 34, '2019-12-28'),
(191, 'Contactor Size 2', 10, '2020-02-07'),
(192, 'Contactor Size 2', 21, '2020-01-11'),
(193, 'Contactor Size 2', 36, '2020-01-12'),
(194, 'Contactor Size 1', 27, '2020-02-08'),
(195, 'Contactor Size 0', 7, '2020-01-03'),
(196, 'Contactor Size 2', 13, '2020-01-04'),
(197, 'Contactor Size 1', 40, '2019-12-26'),
(198, 'Contactor Size 0', 12, '2020-01-06'),
(199, 'Contactor Size 2', 28, '2020-01-29'),
(200, 'Contactor Size 2', 39, '2019-12-19'),
(201, 'Contactor Size 0', 1, '2019-11-30'),
(202, 'Contactor Size 2', 38, '2020-02-05'),
(203, 'Contactor Size 1', 35, '2019-12-18'),
(204, 'Contactor Size 1', 7, '2020-01-11'),
(205, 'Contactor Size 0', 13, '2019-11-27'),
(206, 'Contactor Size 2', 19, '2020-01-11'),
(207, 'Contactor Size 0', 32, '2020-01-10'),
(208, 'Contactor Size 2', 28, '2020-01-20'),
(209, 'Contactor Size 0', 12, '2020-01-27'),
(210, 'Contactor Size 0', 35, '2019-12-31'),
(211, 'Contactor Size 1', 5, '2019-12-16'),
(212, 'Contactor Size 1', 4, '2019-12-03'),
(213, 'Contactor Size 2', 26, '2020-01-20'),
(214, 'Contactor Size 2', 24, '2019-12-08'),
(215, 'Contactor Size 0', 13, '2019-12-20')

end
```

starting to get the tables ready to be iterated:

```
begin

select 
row_number() over (order by shopcalendardate asc) as workcellid
,wc.*
,iwc1.cellcap as item1cellcap
,iwc2.cellcap as item2cellcap
,sc.*
into #w
from #workcell wc
join modelgeneral.vlushopcalendar sc
  on 1=1
left join #itemwc iwc1
  on iwc1.item = wc.item1
  and iwc1.workcell = wc.workcell
left join #itemwc iwc2
  on iwc2.item = wc.item2
  and iwc2.workcell = wc.workcell
where shopcalendardate >= (select min(needdate) from #o)
  and shopcalendardate <= (select max(needdate) from #o)
  and shiftquantity > 0
order by shopcalendardate asc

end

begin 

with orders as (select row_number() over (order by needdate asc) as rn, o.* from #o o)
select *
into #orders 
from orders

end

begin

declare @simulation table (
  rn float,
  orderno float,
  needdate date,
  item varchar(259),
  qty float,
  item1cellcap float,
  item2cellcap float,
  orderqtyleft float,
  workcellid float,
  workcell varchar(259),
  fwdratio float,
  bckratio float,
  item1 varchar(259),
  item2 varchar(259),
  shopcalendardate date,
  shiftquantity float,
  mode varchar(259),
  timesrun float
)

declare @wc table (
  workcellid float,
  workcell varchar(259),
  fwdratio float,
  bckratio float,
  item1 varchar(259),
  item2 varchar(259),
  shopcalendardate date,
  shiftquantity float,
  item1cellcap float,
  item2cellcap float
)

insert into @wc
select
  w.workcellid
  ,w.workcell
  ,w.fwdratio
  ,w.bckratio
  ,w.item1
  ,w.item2
  ,w.shopcalendardate
  ,w.shiftquantity
  ,w.item1cellcap
  ,w.item2cellcap
from #w w
```

the loop is here:

```
declare @depth int
declare @maxdepth int

set @depth = 1
set @maxdepth = 20

while @depth <= @maxdepth

begin

  if not exists
  (
    select top 1 o.rn
    from #orders o 
    join @simulation s
      on s.rn = o.rn
      and s.orderqtyleft > 0
    order by timesrun desc
   )


begin 

      insert into @simulation
      (
      rn,
      orderno,
      needdate,
      item,
      qty,
      item1cellcap,
      item2cellcap,
      orderqtyleft,
      workcellid,
      workcell,
      fwdratio,
      bckratio,
      item1,
      item2,
      shopcalendardate,
      shiftquantity,
      mode,
      timesrun
      )
      select top 1
      o.rn
      ,o.orderno
      ,o.needdate
      ,o.item
      ,o.qty
    ,case
        when w.item1 = o.item
          then 
            case
              when w.item1cellcap - o.qty < 0
                then 0
                else w.item1cellcap - o.qty
            end
        when w.item2 = o.item
          then
            case
              when w.item1cellcap - (w.fwdratio * o.qty) < 0
                then 0
                else floor(w.item1cellcap - (w.fwdratio * o.qty))
            end
       end as item1cellcap
      ,case
        when w.item2 = o.item
          then 
            case
              when w.item2cellcap - o.qty < 0
                then 0
                else w.item2cellcap - o.qty
            end
        when w.item1 = o.item
          then
            case
              when w.item2cellcap - (w.bckratio * o.qty) < 0
                then 0
                else floor(w.item2cellcap - (w.bckratio * o.qty))
            end
       end as item2cellcap
      ,case
        when w.item1 = o.item
          then
            case
              when w.item1cellcap - o.qty < 0
                then ceiling(o.qty - w.item1cellcap)
                else 0
            end
        when w.item2 = o.item
          then
            case
              when w.item2cellcap - o.qty < 0
                then ceiling(o.qty - w.item2cellcap)
                else 0
            end
       end as orderqtyleft
      ,w.workcellid
      ,w.workcell
      ,w.fwdratio
      ,w.bckratio
      ,w.item1
      ,w.item2
      ,w.shopcalendardate
      ,w.shiftquantity
      ,'select fresh order' as mode
      ,@depth
      from #orders o
      left join @simulation t
        on t.rn = o.rn
     cross apply
        (select top 1 
        w.workcellid
        ,w.workcell
        ,w.fwdratio
        ,w.bckratio
        ,w.item1
        ,w.item2
        ,w.shopcalendardate
        ,w.shiftquantity
        ,w.item1cellcap
        ,w.item2cellcap
        from @wc w
        where w.item1cellcap > 0 
          and w.item2cellcap > 0
          and (o.item = w.item1 or o.item = w.item2)
        order by w.workcellid asc) w
    where (o.item = w.item1 or o.item = w.item2) and (w.item1cellcap > 0 and w.item2cellcap > 0)
      and t.rn is null
    order by o.rn asc

    end


    else 

    begin

      insert into @simulation 
      (
      rn,
      orderno,
      needdate,
      item,
      qty,
      item1cellcap,
      item2cellcap,
      orderqtyleft,
      workcellid,
      workcell,
      fwdratio,
      bckratio,
      item1,
      item2,
      shopcalendardate,
      shiftquantity,
      mode,
      timesrun
      )
      select top 1 
      o.rn
      ,o.orderno
      ,o.needdate
      ,o.item
      ,o.qty
      ,case
          when w.item1 = o.item
            then 
              case
                when w.item1cellcap - o.orderqtyleft <= 0
                  then 0
                else w.item1cellcap - o.orderqtyleft
                end
          when w.item2 = o.item
            then
              case
                when w.item1cellcap - (w.fwdratio * o.orderqtyleft) <= 0
                  then 0
                else floor(w.item1cellcap - (w.fwdratio * o.orderqtyleft))
                end
          end as item1cellcap
      ,case
          when w.item2 = o.item
            then 
              case
                when w.item2cellcap - o.orderqtyleft < 0
                  then 0
                else w.item2cellcap - o.orderqtyleft
                end
          when w.item1 = o.item
            then
              case
                when w.item2cellcap - (w.bckratio * o.orderqtyleft) < 0
                  then 0
                else floor(w.item2cellcap - (w.bckratio * o.orderqtyleft))
                end
          end as item2cellcap
      ,case
          when w.item1 = o.item
            then
              case
                when w.item1cellcap - o.orderqtyleft < 0
                  then ceiling(o.orderqtyleft - w.item1cellcap)
                else 0
                end
          when w.item2 = o.item
            then
              case
                when w.item2cellcap - o.orderqtyleft < 0
                  then ceiling(o.orderqtyleft - w.item2cellcap)
                else 0
                end
          end as orderqtyleft
      ,w.workcellid
      ,w.workcell
      ,w.fwdratio
      ,w.bckratio
      ,w.item1
      ,w.item2
      ,w.shopcalendardate
      ,w.shiftquantity
      ,'select existing order' as mode
      ,@depth
     from @simulation o 
     cross apply
        (select top 1 
        w.workcellid
        ,w.workcell
        ,w.fwdratio
        ,w.bckratio
        ,w.item1
        ,w.item2
        ,w.shopcalendardate
        ,w.shiftquantity
        ,w.item1cellcap
        ,w.item2cellcap
        from @wc w
        where w.item1cellcap > 0 
          and w.item2cellcap > 0
          and (o.item = w.item1 or o.item = w.item2)
        order by w.workcellid asc) w
    where (o.item = w.item1 or o.item = w.item2) and o.orderqtyleft > 0
    order by o.rn asc, o.timesrun desc

    end



    set @depth = @depth + 1

    begin

    merge @wc as mytarget
    using (select top 1 workcellid, item1cellcap, item2cellcap from @simulation where orderqtyleft > 0 order by timesrun desc) as mysource
      on mytarget.workcellid = mysource.workcellid

    when matched
      then update
        set
        item1cellcap = mysource.item1cellcap,
        item2cellcap = mysource.item2cellcap
        ;

    end

end

select * 
from @simulation
order by rn

end
```

The output looks like:

[image: output]

Feeling like a failure at the moment, wondering if anyone can help point me in a good direction. Working on Microsoft SQL Server. I set the "while" portion just to test it and to avoid the infinite loop.

-Kevin

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake, here's how I solved it:

```
declare @depth int
declare @maxdepth int
declare @row int

set @row = 1
set @depth = 1
set @maxdepth = 2000

while 
(
(select count(o.rn) 
   from #orders o
    left join @simulation s
      on s.rn = o.rn
    where s.orderqtyleft > 0) > 0

or (select count(o.rn) 
   from #orders o
    left join @simulation s
      on s.rn = o.rn
    where s.rn is null) > 0
)

and

 @depth <= @maxdepth



begin



if
  (
    select top 1 s.rn
    from @simulation s
    where s.orderqtyleft > 0
    order by s.rn desc, s.timesrun desc
  ) is not null

begin

      insert into @simulation 
      (
      rn,
      orderno,
      needdate,
      item,
      qty,
      item1cellcap,
      item2cellcap,
      orderqtyleft,
      orderqtyprocessed,
      workcellid,
      workcell,
      fwdratio,
      bckratio,
      item1,
      item2,
      shopcalendardate,
      shiftquantity,
      mode,
      timesrun
      )
      select top 1 
      o.rn
      ,o.orderno
      ,o.needdate
      ,o.item
      ,o.qty
      ,case
          when w.item1 = o.item
            then 
              case
                when w.item1cellcap - o.orderqtyleft <= 0
                  then 0
                else w.item1cellcap - o.orderqtyleft
                end
          when w.item2 = o.item
            then
              case
                when w.item1cellcap - (w.fwdratio * o.orderqtyleft) <= 0
                  then 0
                else floor(w.item1cellcap - (w.fwdratio * o.orderqtyleft))
                end
          end as item1cellcap
      ,case
          when w.item2 = o.item
            then 
              case
                when w.item2cellcap - o.orderqtyleft < 0
                  then 0
                else w.item2cellcap - o.orderqtyleft
                end
          when w.item1 = o.item
            then
              case
                when w.item2cellcap - (w.bckratio * o.orderqtyleft) < 0
                  then 0
                else floor(w.item2cellcap - (w.bckratio * o.orderqtyleft))
                end
          end as item2cellcap
      ,case
          when w.item1 = o.item
            then
              case
                when w.item1cellcap - o.orderqtyleft < 0
                  then ceiling(o.orderqtyleft - w.item1cellcap)
                else 0
                end
          when w.item2 = o.item
            then
              case
                when w.item2cellcap - o.orderqtyleft < 0
                  then ceiling(o.orderqtyleft - w.item2cellcap)
                else 0
                end
          end as orderqtyleft
      ,case 
          when w.item1 = o.item
            then
              case
                when w.item1cellcap - o.orderqtyleft <= 0
                  then w.item1cellcap
                else o.orderqtyleft
                end
           when w.item2 = o.item
             then
               case
                 when w.item2cellcap - o.orderqtyleft <= 0
                   then w.item2cellcap
                else o.orderqtyleft
                end
        end as orderqtyprocessed
      ,w.workcellid
      ,w.workcell
      ,w.fwdratio
      ,w.bckratio
      ,w.item1
      ,w.item2
      ,w.shopcalendardate
      ,w.shiftquantity
      ,'select existing order' as mode
      ,@depth
     from @simulation o 
     cross apply
        (select top 1 
        w.workcellid
        ,w.workcell
        ,w.fwdratio
        ,w.bckratio
        ,w.item1
        ,w.item2
        ,w.shopcalendardate
        ,w.shiftquantity
        ,w.item1cellcap
        ,w.item2cellcap
        from @wc w
        where w.item1cellcap > 0 
          and (o.item = w.item1 or o.item = w.item2)
        order by w.workcellid asc) w
    where (o.item = w.item1 or o.item = w.item2) and o.orderqtyleft > 0 and o.rn = @row
    order by o.rn asc, o.timesrun desc

end

begin

if
  (
    select top 1 o.rn
    from #orders o
    left join @simulation s
      on s.rn = o.rn
    where s.rn is null and o.rn = @row
    order by o.rn asc
   ) is not null

begin

      insert into @simulation
      (
      rn,
      orderno,
      needdate,
      item,
      qty,
      item1cellcap,
      item2cellcap,
      orderqtyleft,
      orderqtyprocessed,
      workcellid,
      workcell,
      fwdratio,
      bckratio,
      item1,
      item2,
      shopcalendardate,
      shiftquantity,
      mode,
      timesrun
      )
      select top 1
      o.rn
      ,o.orderno
      ,o.needdate
      ,o.item
      ,o.qty
    ,case
        when w.item1 = o.item
          then 
            case
              when w.item1cellcap - o.qty < 0
                then 0
                else w.item1cellcap - o.qty
            end
        when w.item2 = o.item
          then
            case
              when w.item1cellcap - (w.fwdratio * o.qty) < 0
                then 0
                else floor(w.item1cellcap - (w.fwdratio * o.qty))
            end
       end as item1cellcap
      ,case
        when w.item2 = o.item
          then 
            case
              when w.item2cellcap - o.qty < 0
                then 0
                else w.item2cellcap - o.qty
            end
        when w.item1 = o.item
          then
            case
              when w.item2cellcap - (w.bckratio * o.qty) < 0
                then 0
                else floor(w.item2cellcap - (w.bckratio * o.qty))
            end
       end as item2cellcap
      ,case
        when w.item1 = o.item
          then
            case
              when w.item1cellcap - o.qty < 0
                then ceiling(o.qty - w.item1cellcap)
                else 0
            end
        when w.item2 = o.item
          then
            case
              when w.item2cellcap - o.qty < 0
                then ceiling(o.qty - w.item2cellcap)
                else 0
            end
       end as orderqtyleft
       ,case
         when w.item1 = o.item
           then
             case 
               when w.item1cellcap - o.qty <= 0
                 then w.item1cellcap
                 else o.qty
              end
          when w.item2 = o.item
            then
              case
                when w.item2cellcap - o.qty <= 0
                  then w.item2cellcap
                  else o.qty
              end
         end as orderqtyprocessed
      ,w.workcellid
      ,w.workcell
      ,w.fwdratio
      ,w.bckratio
      ,w.item1
      ,w.item2
      ,w.shopcalendardate
      ,w.shiftquantity
      ,'select fresh order' as mode
      ,@depth
      from #orders o
      left join @simulation t
        on t.rn = o.rn
     cross apply
        (select top 1 
        w.workcellid
        ,w.workcell
        ,w.fwdratio
        ,w.bckratio
        ,w.item1
        ,w.item2
        ,w.shopcalendardate
        ,w.shiftquantity
        ,w.item1cellcap
        ,w.item2cellcap
        from @wc w
        where w.item1cellcap > 0 
          and (o.item = w.item1 or o.item = w.item2)
        order by w.workcellid asc) w
    where (o.item = w.item1 or o.item = w.item2) and w.item1cellcap > 0 and o.rn = @row
      and t.rn is null
    order by o.rn asc

end






end

begin

if (
    select top 1 s.orderqtyleft from @simulation s where s.rn = @row order by s.timesrun desc
    ) = 0


    set @row = @row + 1

end


    set @depth = @depth + 1

    begin

    merge @wc as mytarget
    using (select top 1 workcellid, item1cellcap, item2cellcap from @simulation where orderqtyleft >= 0 order by timesrun desc) as mysource
      on mytarget.workcellid = mysource.workcellid

    when matched
      then update
        set
        item1cellcap = mysource.item1cellcap,
        item2cellcap = mysource.item2cellcap
        ;

    end

end

select * 
from @simulation
order by rn

end
```